# Javascript autocomplete without overlapping results

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have autocomplete textbox that need some improvements. It works fine if you type slow but if you type fast then I get multiply results overlap. For example if I erase 1 by 1 letter all to the end I get result as few letters are in textbox. Later results appear correct but it looks like in slow-motion.

I've tried with abort() method for HTTP request when new one is coming but that didn’t solve the problem.

Method is triggered onkeyup of textbox.

Question is how to stop previous request and take care just for current one.

```js
function getResults(inputValue){
 var url="Ajax/acResults.aspx";
 url=url+"?input="+inputValue;
        url=url+"&idrnd="+Math.random();

 var xmlHttpPC=GetXmlHttpObject();
 xmlHttpPC.onreadystatechange=function(){
     if (xmlHttpPC.readyState==4){ 
            document.getElementById("resultBox").innerHTML=xmlHttpPC.responseText;
        }
 };
 xmlHttpPC.open("GET",url,true);
 xmlHttpPC.send(null);
}

function GetXmlHttpObject(){
  var xmlHttp=null;
  try
    {
    // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
    xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
  catch (e)
    {
    // Internet Explorer
    try
      {
      xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      }
    catch (e)
      {
      xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    }
  return xmlHttp;
}
```

---

After some testing I end up with combination of abort method and check value of XMLHttpRequest object:

```js
var xmlHttpPC=null;
function getResults(inputValue){
 var url="Ajax/acResults.aspx";
 url=url+"?input="+inputValue;
    url+="&idrnd="+Math.random();

 if (xmlHttpPC!=null) {
        xmlHttpPC.abort();
        xmlHttpPC = null;
    } 
    if (xmlHttpPC==null) {
        xmlHttpPC=GetXmlHttpObject();
    }
  
 xmlHttpPC.onreadystatechange=function(){
     if (xmlHttpPC.readyState==4){ 
            document.getElementById("resultBox").innerHTML=xmlHttpPC.responseText;
            xmlHttpPC=null;
        }
 };
 xmlHttpPC.open("GET",url,true);
 xmlHttpPC.send(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achive it by checking flag variables or you may just compare xmlhttp variable with null , somthing like as below -

```
var xmlHttp=null;
    function getResults(inputValue){
       if(xmlHttp!=null)
           return;
        //--------
            //-------
            if (xmlHttpPC.readyState==4)
                { 
                document.getElementById("resultBox").innerHTML=xmlHttpPC.responseText;
                xmlHttp=null;
                }
        };
        //--------
    }

    function GetXmlHttpObject(){
      xmlHttp=null;
      //------
    }
```

Comment: I end up with combination of flag check and abort method of XMLHttpRequest object.

Answer (score 0):

use debounce to send the ajax call only if no letter has been removed or added for 150ms (change the value as you want):

```
    function debounce(fn, delay) {
      var timer = null;
      return function () {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
          fn.apply(context, args);
        }, delay);
      };
    }

    var getResultsDebounced = debounce(getResults, 150); // now you have a new function called getResultsDebounced which being triggered after idle of 150ms

whatever.addEventListener("keyup",getResultsDebounced, false);
```